# WCF Rest and Soap

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

I try to write simple subscription service with soap and rest operations. This is my code:
SubsService.svc:

```
namespace SubscriptionService
{
    public class SubsService : ISubsService
    {
        public string RegisterEvent(string serviceId, string name, string description)
        {
            return "ok";
        }

        public void UnregisterEvent(string serviceId, string name)
        {
            // TO DO
        }

        public void RiseEvent(string serviceId, string name)
        {
            // TO DO
        }

        public string EventsList(string token)
        {
            return token;
        }

        public void Subscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name)
        {
            // TO DO
        }

        public void UnSubscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name)
        {
            // TO DO
        }
    }
}
```

ISubsService.cs:

```
namespace SubscriptionService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISubsService
    {
        // SOA
        [OperationContract]
        string RegisterEvent(string serviceId, string name, string description);

        [OperationContract]
        void UnregisterEvent(string serviceId, string name);

        [OperationContract]
        void RiseEvent(string serviceId, string name);

        // REST
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "events?token={token}")]
        string EventsList(string token);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "subscribe?token={token}&serviceId={serviceId}&name={name}")]
        void Subscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "unsubscribe?token={token}&serviceId={serviceId}&name={name}")]
        void UnSubscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name);
    }
}
```

and web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SubscriptionService.SubsService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SubscriptionService.ISubsService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SubscriptionService.ISubsService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I try to access http://localhost:2354/SubsService.svc, I get error:

```
Operation 'RegisterEvent' of contract 'ISubsService' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.
```

But RegisterEvent has to be soap operation. What is wrong with my code? Something in web.config?

Comment: Just use two interfaces , one for your soap and the other for your REST this way you would have two endpoints